# iOS XPC analog in windows 10

Tags: ios, windows, macos, uwp, xpc

Do Windows 10 has any analogy to [XPC](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/xpc) of iOS and macOS platform?

Basically XPC lets you run safely process out of main application loop and communicate with it.

Comment: Yes, you can use [out-of-proc WinRT components](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Creating-a-Windows-Runtime-ed84af9d) or you can use CreateProcess with redirected stdio or anonymous pipes. OOP WinRT will be easiest if you have the ability to use it. Check

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT  can I use this feature for windows store apps?

Comment: Yes, you can use these in a UWP app and submit it to the Windows Store. [The sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Creating-a-Windows-Runtime-ed84af9d#content) passes the WACK checks modulo the lack of real icon images.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT thank you. I think you can qualify your comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [out-of-proc (OOP) WinRT components](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Creating-a-Windows-Runtime-ed84af9d) to spawn a separate process and communicate with it via a rich object model. This is probably the best choice if you are able to modify the app you're calling to expose a WinRT API. See [this sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Creating-a-Windows-Runtime-ed84af9d#content) for more info.

You can also go the old-fashioned route and call `CreateProcess` and communicate with the spawned process via redirected stdio, or via pipes. That's probably easier to do from an infrastructure perspective, but not as nice from a programmability perspective.

Both these approaches are WACK-compliant and can be submitted through the Windows Store.